# localized vocabulary-names dont show up in views drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-views, vocabulary

i got a view in drupal that shows terms and their corresponding vocabulary-name to group those terms. 
Problem: When i switch the language just the terms show their translated versions, the vocabulary-names stay in the original language.

Any idea how to solve that? All hints are appreciated :)

Thanks in advance
Fab

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: what you mean by "anything"? lol
I guess i did, yes. I also got the i18n-Module installed. But nothing works as excpected and didnt found any working answer somewhere on the net.